# Can/does rust have a C question mark colon equivalent

Tags: rust, operators, porting

Does Rust have any equivalent to

x = a ? b : c;

I would guess someone could write a macro that writes out

```
    if a { 
        b 
    } else { 
        c 
    }
```

maybe in a crate somewhere, if not in core?

```
x = a | b;
```

would be useful as well with C assumptions for truth being non zero.

(I'm porting Java, seems Rust is a lot more verbose even than Java)

Comment: *I'm porting Java, seems Rust is a lot more verbose even than Java* — writing Java in Rust is likely more verbose than writing Java in Java. My guess is that writing Rust in Rust is equally or less verbose than Java in Java.

Comment: *maybe in a crate somewhere* — FYI, questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.